# How to automatically execute a command in a terminal after a period without activity?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I've been looking for an option or script that executes a command after the terminal has been idle (that's no input nor output).

The closest thing I've found is setting the `TMOUT=seconds` variable so the terminal automatically closes. This can be done directly or adding the line to `$HOME/.profile`

What I'm trying to do is that the gnome-terminal on my desktop resets or clears itself after not being used for, let's say, 5 minutes.

Comment: I think it's not possible without the use of an additional tool like GNU's screen, tmux or terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the output of `w` in a cron job. See the row `IDLE`. This is the time since the last keystroke is made in the shell:

```
user@host:~# w
 20:29:12 up  4:04,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    1.2.3.4          18:24    0.00s  0.23s  0.00s w
user@host:~# sleep 10 && w
 20:29:26 up  4:04,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    1.2.3.4          18:24   10.00s  0.23s  0.00s w
```

So, write a cron job that reads this line and when the number is over 300 (5 mins) execute your command.

Comment: I see... I don't know a lot about how cron works, or how to read the line (something like grep would do, i supose) but I'll have a look later. I supose the script would have to be set in each terminal as startup, am I wrong? And then, get the pts/# value for each one, read the output of w and execute "reset" into that pts (or tty). I'll keep looking into it, thanks!

Comment: You run the script in a defined interval with `cron` (not as startup, always). Have a look at `cron`, you will find thousands of howto's to write `cron` jobs.

Comment: I could post the [same comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/395279/how-to-automatically-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal-after-a-period-without-acti#comment506294_395292) to this answer. It does not apply to what the OP is asking. This approach does not enable you to control the terminal itself.